# Solving all possible expressions from a given set of numbers

Tags: c++, algorithm, expression

Recently I came across a question which went something like this. You are given `n` numbers and the three operators `+`, `-`, and `*`. Using the first `n-1` numbers and the three given operators you have to check if there is a way to combine them to give the `nth' number as the solution.

The input is a set of numbers and the output is a `Y` or `N`.

Example

Given numbers `10 9 7 1 10 8`. We can use the `n-1` numbers exactly once. The output of the example is `Y` because there exists a solution i.e. `(10-10)*9+(7+1)=8`.

My approach till now.

I am having difficulty finding a non-brute force approach to the problem. The basic idea I'm using is this.
I'll first compute each permutation of the set of `n-1` numbers and then insert in each of the `n-2` spaces between the numbers, all the possible permutations of the operators and evaluate the resulting expression. I have not been able to code this and moreover I doubt that this is even correct. 
Please guide me on how to go about solving the problem. I'm using `C++`.

Comment: You will end up brute force anyway. However, it can be improved by memoization. What is the limit of `n`?

Comment: I am not too sure but it was 100 and what exactly is memoization?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization

Comment: Do you need to use all the numbers, and are you always going to have ints?

Comment: @avitevet Yes. All ints and and you have to use all the numbers and you can use any or all of the operators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that basically you'll be creating a very large set of trees.  The top of the tree has n-1 numbers.  You create the next level of the tree by:

- permuting the numbers
- Reducing the set by combining a subset of adjacent numbers using a permutation of the operations

Repeat that until the set has been reduced to size 1.

With your example: `10 9 7 1 10 8`

- Create a permutation of the M numbers: `10 10 9 7 1`
- Select a subset of adjacent number pairs of size Q:   `10 10` and `7 1`
- Create a permutation of the operations of size Q: `*` and `*`
- Reduce the set by combining the adjacent number pairs with the operations: `10*10 => 100` and `7*1 ==> 7`
- Your new reduced set (what I think of as the next level of the tree) is `100 9 7`

Repeat.  You'll be creating a new tree for each permutation of the numbers, for each subset of adjacent numbers, and for each permutation of operations.  Keep in mind that size Q of the subset of adjacent numbers can be in [1, M /2].

For "large" N, this will be both memory and compute intensive.  Actual implementation will probably depend on what hardware you actually have available.  Some optimizations could be:

- If you are using a brute force approach, start with keeping the size Q as close to M / 2 as possible.  This will reduce the number of intermediate sets.
- Memoization may be helpful, but there will be such a vast set of possible combinations that it's probably faster to just do the int add/mul/sub, which (if you're on Intel) take 1 or maybe 3 cycles.
- Since there's such a large number of possible reduce trees, I think you'll need to use something like a genetic algorithm to select permutations.

Also, this type of problem is not really the strength of C++... it would be easier to write this in a language with more functional features like scala or even ruby.

Cool problem BTW.

Answer (score 1):

Two approaches come to mind:

1. use constraint programming (CP) (eclipse, gnu prolog, ...) over integer domains. The numbers and the operators are given, CP will exhaustively search for all possible solutions, or if you are a bit clever, or your n is inconveniently large, you can guide the search by noting that you don't need to permute X and Y if the operator is commutative (+, *). Use this if you need to get the job done, as the code is about 20 lines.
2. an oldish book by Douglas Hofstadter (of GEB fame) titled 'Fluid Concepts and Creative Analogies' has Chapter 3 by Daniel Defays describing a cognitive science approach to the problem (Numbo: A Study in Cognition and Recognition). Reproducing that would be somewhat involved, but if the book is any indication, it would be pure fun.